# cross compile a c program with visual studio community

Tags: visual-studio, cross-compiling, windows-arm64

I am working on an ARM64 computer with Windows 10 (Windows ARM).

I have installed Visual Studio Community. I can create C/C++ Console programs. It works fine. But generated binary files are compiled for an ARM target.

Is there a way to generate x86 (or x86_64) binary files ?

I have looked inside project configuration but I did not find anything.

Do you know where I can select binary output platform in visual studio ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you used the "Console App" template for C++ when you created the project, then the project was probably created with two 'platform' configurations: x64 and win32. Change the "active platform" to 'win32'. You can make that change in the "Configuration Manager" or in the standard toolbar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But where is arm configuration ? In fact i can only build for x86 and x64…